# how to plot a value in the tensor using matplotlib

Tags: python, plot

I have tensor of shape (50,1024) , 50 is the batch size and 1024 is the time samples of signal amplitudes. how to plot one signal from the batch of 50 ? here is a code snippet i tried something similar to that i do in Matlab but that dont work for me. It shows error

```
t = np.arange(0.,1024.,1.)
plt.plot(t,x[1,:])
plt.title('original')
plt.show()
```

how to plot multiple figures in python ?

I have to plot three variables x,y,z

```
t = np.arange(0.,1024.,1.)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t,x[1,:])
plt.title('original')
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(t[1:64],y[1,:])
plt.title('encoded')
plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(t,z[1,:])
plt.title('reconstructed')
```

Comment: What is the error shown? Also `x[1,:]` doesn't seem like correct syntax. Another question - do you want the three variables in a single plot or separate plots?

Comment: Is t actually representing something here? If you just do `plot(x[1,:])` it should plot the line in the same way since t is just a range representing the length of the array. Your second plot will fail because you are taking  a slice of t that is only length 63 and plotting against a length 1024 slice of y. If that doesn't help tell is what the errors are.